# Loop through Controls on a Userform to hide specific controls

Tags: vba, excel-2013

I have looked through numerous posts on this and come up with the solution below, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to code this.

The cases are based on a ComboBox value 0 to 8 that the user chooses and then Labels and TextBoxes will show up based on the number in the ComboBox.

All of the Labels and TextBoxes I want to hide or show start with "b" and then the number 1 through 8 as you can see in the code below.  I appreciate any suggestions to improve the efficiency of the loops I have running.

```
 Select Case LendStart.lsNumBorr.Value
    Case Is = 0
        For Each ctrl In LendStart.Controls
            If Left(ctrl.Name, 1) = "b" Then
                ctrl.Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    Case Is = 1
        For Each ctrl In LendStart.Controls
            If Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b1" Then
                ctrl.Visible = True
                    If Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b2" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b3" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b4" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b5" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b6" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b7" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b8" Then
                        ctrl.Visible = False
                    End If
            End If
        Next
    Case Is = 2
        For Each ctrl In LendStart.Controls
            If Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b1" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b2" Then
                ctrl.Visible = True
                    If Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b3" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b4" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b5" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b6" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b7" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b8" Then
                        ctrl.Visible = False
                    End If
            End If
        Next
 End Select
```

Comment: I can post this question on the other site if its too broad and because the code works.  I was looking for suggestions to streamline the loops and `If` statements in the current code.  Thank you.  I do appreciate the help and feedback on where to post certain questions as I am still learning all of the Stack sites.

Comment: Where does `a` come from?`

Comment: @TimWilliams, I updated the code to reflect how it works now, but since this question is seeming to cause an issue and may not fall into the scope of the rules; I think I am going to delete it.  Thank you all for taking a look at this and my apologies if this question caused any issues.

Comment: Looking at Code Review - there are only 7 questions tagged VBA this month - leaving those here on SO isn't going to clutter up the place (and frankly those are some of the more-interesting questions that show up here) so asking folk to move them to a lightly-trafficked location isn't going to get them much help. Code can be technically "working" but still be capable of significant improvement: these things are part-and-parcel of learning to code well, and don't necessarily need to be partitioned off into a separate location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim i As Long, numBorr, firstTwo

    numBorr = LendStart.lsNumBorr.Value

    For Each ctrl In LendStart.Controls
        If Left(ctrl.Name, 1) = "b" Then

            firstTwo = Left(ctrl.Name, 2)

            For i = 1 To 8
                If firstTwo = "b" & i Then
                    ctrl.Visible = (i <= numBorr)
                End If
            Next i

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note there is a logic error in your posted code:

```
If Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b1" Then
    ctrl.Visible = True
    If Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b2" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b3" Or _
       Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b4" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b5" Or _
       Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b6" Or Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b7" Or _
       Left(ctrl.Name, 2) = "b8" Then

                    ctrl.Visible = False
    End If
End If
```

The outer `If` checks for "b1" but in that case the inner `If` will never pass

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with this and pointing out the error in the logic of my code.